# Android Board casting Application

Tags: android, notifications, push

Hi we like to build from scratch an application that has the following purpose and function.

Situation: 
A restaurant chain owner has multiple outlet, Food Menu is currently displayed on Android Tablet.

Problem: 
Right now the update is done manually on each tablet, pricing and pictures of food.

Improvement:
A Single Table/Computer to push information, data, pictures to multiple android tablet at various restaurant.

How can we build something like that.

Looking forward to the experts here.

Sincerely thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Push Notification** is the answer. You can implement it in multiple way; for example Parse.

The Parse library provides push notifications by using Google Cloud Messaging (GCM).
Connect your app to Parse. Before getting started, you will need to set up and connect your app to Parse. ...
Send a Test Push Notification. At this point, you're ready to send push notifications. ...
Customizing Notifications.

Furthermore, you can follow these links 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_push_notification.htm
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-get-started-with-push-notifications-on-android--cms-25870
for parse https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications